How to deal with multiple dictionary entries that have identical keys but different values (json returned from API)
So the problem is the following I made a station on the Banco do Brasil website using the hidden Api that returned me values from 414 cities However It happened crazy that for each who made the application had the brilliant idea of not formatting any key says the all the keys were with the same name “NomeBeneficiario” (15 thousand lines), I find it incredible that this fact happened, certainly an exceptional error
Does anyone know how to reformat, or how to extract the values I want?
and this is just a small portion of the json I used as an example, the original has 15,000 lines, I use one looping do collect data
{
    "January": {
        "quantidadeBeneficio": 43,
        "indicadorContinuarPesquisa": "N",
        "quantidadeOcorrencia": [
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "ITAMARAJU                                         -BA"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "ICS   - ICMS ESTADUAL"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "DATA                PARCELA                                   VALOR DISTRIBUIDO"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "03.01.2023        COTA-PARTE                                        146.746,17C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                      22.011,92D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                     29.349,23D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  TOTAL NA DATA                                      95.385,02C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "10.01.2023        COTA-PARTE                                         30.770,32C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                       4.615,54D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                      6.154,06D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  TOTAL NA DATA                                      20.000,72C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "17.01.2023        COTA-PARTE                                        646.359,98C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                      96.953,99D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                    129.271,99D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  TOTAL NA DATA                                     420.134,00C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "24.01.2023        COTA-PARTE                                        186.707,09C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                      28.006,06D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                     37.341,41D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  TOTAL NA DATA                                     121.359,62C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "31.01.2023        COTA-PARTE                                        345.724,35C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                      51.858,65D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                     69.144,87D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  TOTAL NA DATA                                     224.720,83C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "TOTAL POR PARCELA / NATUREZA"
            }, 
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  COTA-PARTE                                      1.356.307,91C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                     203.446,16D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                    271.261,56D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEBITO FUNDO                                      474.707,72D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  CREDITO FUNDO                                   1.356.307,91C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "TOTAL DISTRIBUIDO NO PERIODO"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEBITO BENEF.                                     474.707,72D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  CREDITO BENEF.                                  1.356.307,91C"
            }
        ]
    },
    "February": {
        "quantidadeBeneficio": 38,
        "indicadorContinuarPesquisa": "N",
        "quantidadeOcorrencia": [
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "ITAMARAJU                                         -BA"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "ICS   - ICMS ESTADUAL"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "DATA                PARCELA                                   VALOR DISTRIBUIDO"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "07.02.2023        COTA-PARTE                                        292.297,18C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                      43.844,57D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                     58.459,43D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  TOTAL NA DATA                                     189.993,18C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "14.02.2023        COTA-PARTE                                        579.379,81C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                      86.906,97D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                    115.875,96D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  TOTAL NA DATA                                     376.596,88C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "23.02.2023        COTA-PARTE                                        231.268,18C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                      34.690,22D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                     46.253,63D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  TOTAL NA DATA                                     150.324,33C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "28.02.2023        COTA-PARTE                                        255.599,39C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                      38.339,90D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                     51.119,87D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  TOTAL NA DATA                                     166.139,62C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "TOTAL POR PARCELA / NATUREZA"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  COTA-PARTE                                      1.358.544,56C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                     203.781,66D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                    271.708,89D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEBITO FUNDO                                      475.490,55D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  CREDITO FUNDO                                   1.358.544,56C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "TOTAL DISTRIBUIDO NO PERIODO"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEBITO BENEF.                                     475.490,55D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  CREDITO BENEF.                                  1.358.544,56C"
            }
        ]
    },
    "March": {
        "quantidadeBeneficio": 38,
        "indicadorContinuarPesquisa": "N",
        "quantidadeOcorrencia": [
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "ITAMARAJU                                         -BA"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "ICS   - ICMS ESTADUAL"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "DATA                PARCELA                                   VALOR DISTRIBUIDO"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "07.03.2023        COTA-PARTE                                        539.023,36C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                      80.853,50D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                    107.804,67D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  TOTAL NA DATA                                     350.365,19C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "14.03.2023        COTA-PARTE                                        541.413,33C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                      81.211,99D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                    108.282,66D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  TOTAL NA DATA                                     351.918,68C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "21.03.2023        COTA-PARTE                                        190.618,47C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                      28.592,77D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                     38.123,69D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  TOTAL NA DATA                                     123.902,01C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "28.03.2023        COTA-PARTE                                        226.588,95C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                      33.988,34D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                     45.317,79D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  TOTAL NA DATA                                     147.282,82C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "TOTAL POR PARCELA / NATUREZA"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  COTA-PARTE                                      1.497.644,11C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                     224.646,60D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                    299.528,81D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEBITO FUNDO                                      524.175,41D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  CREDITO FUNDO                                   1.497.644,11C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "TOTAL DISTRIBUIDO NO PERIODO"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEBITO BENEF.                                     524.175,41D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  CREDITO BENEF.                                  1.497.644,11C"
            }
        ]
    },
    "April": {
        "quantidadeBeneficio": 38,
        "indicadorContinuarPesquisa": "N",
        "quantidadeOcorrencia": [
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "ITAMARAJU                                         -BA"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "ICS   - ICMS ESTADUAL"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "DATA                PARCELA                                   VALOR DISTRIBUIDO"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "04.04.2023        COTA-PARTE                                        627.139,78C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                      94.070,96D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                    125.427,95D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  TOTAL NA DATA                                     407.640,87C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "11.04.2023        COTA-PARTE                                         93.830,51C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                      14.074,57D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                     18.766,10D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  TOTAL NA DATA                                      60.989,84C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "18.04.2023        COTA-PARTE                                        674.866,62C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                     101.229,99D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                    134.973,32D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  TOTAL NA DATA                                     438.663,31C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "25.04.2023        COTA-PARTE                                        192.545,93C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                      28.881,88D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                     38.509,18D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  TOTAL NA DATA                                     125.154,87C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "TOTAL POR PARCELA / NATUREZA"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  COTA-PARTE                                      1.588.382,84C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                     238.257,40D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                    317.676,55D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEBITO FUNDO                                      555.933,95D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  CREDITO FUNDO                                   1.588.382,84C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "TOTAL DISTRIBUIDO NO PERIODO"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEBITO BENEF.                                     555.933,95D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  CREDITO BENEF.                                  1.588.382,84C"
            }
        ]
    },
    "May": {
        "quantidadeBeneficio": 43,
        "indicadorContinuarPesquisa": "N",
        "quantidadeOcorrencia": [
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "ITAMARAJU                                         -BA"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "ICS   - ICMS ESTADUAL"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "DATA                PARCELA                                   VALOR DISTRIBUIDO"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "03.05.2023        COTA-PARTE                                        873.381,70C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                     131.007,25D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                    174.676,34D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  TOTAL NA DATA                                     567.698,11C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "09.05.2023        COTA-PARTE                                         63.508,36C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                       9.526,25D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                     12.701,67D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  TOTAL NA DATA                                      41.280,44C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "16.05.2023        COTA-PARTE                                        642.245,37C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                      96.336,80D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                    128.449,07D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  TOTAL NA DATA                                     417.459,50C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "23.05.2023        COTA-PARTE                                        208.658,97C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                      31.298,84D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                     41.731,79D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  TOTAL NA DATA                                     135.628,34C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "30.05.2023        COTA-PARTE                                        361.045,93C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO SAUDE                                      54.156,88D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  DEDUCAO FUNDEB                                     72.209,18D"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "                  TOTAL NA DATA                                     234.679,87C"
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": ""
            },
            {
                "nomeBeneficio": "TOTAL POR PARCELA / NATUREZA"
            },
            {


            {
                                     
    }
}

i have used this code to print the values after identify "total Parcela" and returned the last elements]
import json
import polars as pl

with open(r"C:\Users\Henrique RIbeiro\Documents\projetos em andamentos\daf extração\daf_extractions\json4\renomeados\ABAIRA_dados_anuais.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

for month in months:
    if month in data:
        after_total_parcela = False
        print(f"{month}")
        
        # Iterate over each month
        for item in data[month]['quantidadeOcorrencia']:
            benefit_name = item.get('nomeBeneficio', '').strip()
            if benefit_name == "TOTAL POR PARCELA / NATUREZA":
                after_total_parcela = True
            elif after_total_parcela and benefit_name:
                print(benefit_name)
        
        print("\n")  


What code did you try? The JSON looks fine to me.

This is not an error, but a list of dictionaries, which is totally valid.

it may even be valid and work, but I only need to extract a few values from this json,
I did an extraction for 414 municipalities, and the json are organized by month (414 different files)
There are more than 15,000 lines and there is no way to identify them manually. The goal is to create an excel spreadsheet with only the values I want, and precisely because the keys are repeated, I can't get the identifier.

Right.  for name in data['January']['quantidadeOcorrencia']: / print( name['nomeBeneficio']).

this returns the values, but I only need the ones below "TOTAL PARCELA \ NATUREZA" for each month

and this is just a small portion of the json I used as an example, the original has 15,000 lines

Please describe what data specifically you want. We can't read your mind.
